# How to setup a simple network that can use several IP ranges?

Tags: networking, subnet

100% of the time, I would simply setup an office network to use the usual, 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.255 range

For the fist time I found myself needing to put some devices on different ranges while allowing all devices on the network to see each other.

The plan is to have the following IP assignments / ranges:
192.168.1.xxx = Computers 
192.168.2.xxx = IP Phones
192.168.3.xxx = Surveillance Systems
192.168.43.xxx = Special Devices  (notice that this one's 3rd octet is at .43)

All of the above connects to the same group of network switches, gets internet from router @ 192.168.1.1 , and must be accessible to each other .

Can this be done with need for any special hardware? Just subnet setting of some sort?

Would appreciate some help from the network experts around here. Thank you!

**UPDATE: 2018-07-07 Saturday 12:43 PM**

I have solved it through some help, but not sure if it's the most elegant way.

I discovered subnet calculators, and by tinkering, I have set all my devices to use subnet 255.255.128.0

[image]

Now all devices from 192.168.1.x to 192.168.43.x are able to ping each other :)

The question now is, is this OK? Or am I making my network slow for openning up so many 3rd octet possibilities?

NOTE to answer some of the common questions:
 1. WHY NOT JUST PUT ALL DEVICES on 192.168.1.x ? 
Answer 1: For the sake of organizing IP addresses in groups, and avoiding IP conflicts by mistake.

Answer 2: Some devices we add and remove come with static IP address by default and it was becoming quite of a hassle to have to change IPs regularly just to manage these devices

Answer 3: We needed our main computers to be able to connect to devices in different IP settings / subnets easily , in and out, without having to keep changing the main computers' ip addresses to connect to devices on different subnets. This was part of the hassle.

Comment: Making the subnet larger is one solution but for a "simple network" to be setup as class b with a `/16` bitmask seems like overkill to me. You could get a router and have it route only the IP address(es) of the specific admin machine(s) on the different subnets over to `192.168.3.x` and `192.168.43.x` subnets. Since you say this is a simple network then I assume you could put the devices from the `192.168.3.x` and `192.168.43.x` subnets onto the `192.168.1.x` subnet instead and assign IP settings accordingly.

Comment: You don't seem to be worried about broadcast traffic on the subnets being on the network of the separate subnets since they all connect to a switch so if that's the case, then why not put those all on the same subnet instead? You don't even necessarily need to go with a `/16` bit mask even if you have more than 254 devices assigned IP addresses on the same subnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely do what you describe.  Network settings that would probably work might be:

Network: 192.168.0.0 (/16)

Netmask: 255.255.0.0

Gateway: 192.168.1.1

It isn't clear though why you need the surveillance devices and the IP phones and the special devices all to communicate with one another.  The few IP cameras I'm aware of can't use IP phones to make phone calls (for example).

If they do need to communicate, it isn't clear why you wouldn't simply use: 192.168.0.0/20 and just put them on 192.168.0, 192.168.1, 192.168.2, and 192.168.3.

Your plan seems a little conflicted, so maybe it would make sense to put a little more thought into it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advise Startibartfast. One of the reasons we need all to be communicating on same network is for our admins to just use 1 PC and 1 ip setting and be able to access all devices if need to. We found ourselves having to keep changing ip address just to access specific devices set to use other subnets. I think your recommendation here will work for us. Being noob, i never thought of setting subnet other than what was taught to me, 255.255.255.0 . Ill look more into this now.

Answer (score 0):

Advice: Don't use different IP ranges on the same LAN segment. While in principle this is possible, you'll get funny effects which will take you a long time to debug. The effort just isn't worth it.

If you have different types of devices, put them on different LAN segments. You can do that physically by placing and configuring your routers correctly, or if the devices are evenly distributed in your network and you can't do that, but using [VLAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_LAN). This basically overlays different "virtual" LAN segments on a single physical LAN segment, and then you can give each virtual LAN segment the correct IP range.

**Edit**

Imagine VLAN as "cables of different colors inside your LAN cables". Think of the normal LAN cables as "white". You need a special "adapter" (= VLAN network interface) to get from a colored cable to a white cable, which then appears as an additional port on the connected computer. If you want the differently colored cables to communicate with each other, you need a router to connect them, just like you'd need a router to connect different physical LAN segments. So this router will have adapters for each colored cables, and will forward packets between the colored cables. You can also have several of these routers, and they can be integrated into existing computers.

If you just need the admin computer to be able to access all subnets, just give the admin computer all colored adapters. Then you don't need a router.

If you are not entirely clear what a LAN segment/subnet/broadcast domain is, and why you'd need several, read up on this. It's a very fundamental and important networking concept.

So it all boils down to *why* you want different `192.168.2.x`, `192.168.3.x` etc: Is it just to better remember the numbers? Or does it have other consequences, like restricting which part of the network can communicate with which other part? Or which part of your whole network is reached with a broadcast?

If it's just to better remember the numbers, use a `192.168.x.x/16`single segment. If it has other consequences, use multiple segments.

Comment: im trying to follow your idea here, but i can't quite get a grasp. I'll look into VLAn stuffs more. Tnx for the lead. 
Btw, will VLAN allow computers on 192.168.1.x communicate with devices on 192.168.5.x and others? that's really the point here.. Things are setup on separate ranges,and i need the admin computer to be able to access all devices on network for easy maintenance, and even pinging them just to monitor if they're up, and etc